# Can you think of a reason why windows might not enable audio if noone is logged in?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, directshow, windows-server-2012

I'm having a bizarre problem with some virtual servers created to record podcasts. They run on amazon AWS as windows server 2012 instances and a small c# app tells FFMPEG to do the heavy lifting of capturing from the virtual screen and reading from the virtual sound card (Virtual Audio Cable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Audio_Cable) via DirectShow filters

The problem I have is if I leave the machine to do its stuff unattended, the recordings are sometimes silent. If I log in via VNC and watch it doing its stuff the audio is recorded just fine. All other aspects of the test op are the same, and the virtual machine is shut down between successive recordings so each one should theoretically be a clean slate. The app runs under a logged in session (hence the use of VNC rather than RDP)

I'm now wondering if there is some optimisation of the windows sound engine whereby it doesn't bother playing audio if it thinks noone is listening. The confusing thing to me is that not every virtual machine suffers these problems; some of them record fine (and they're all created from the same seed virtual hard disk image) in unattended mode

I'm asking this question with the aim of getting together a list of things I can check/look into/debug.. I don't have much knowledge of how MME/DirectSound/WASAPI work internally...

Comment: This machine does; it has Virtual Audio Cable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Audio_Cable) installed.. It provides a virtal audio channel for audio playing apps to dump data into, and ffmpeg can read it out. As noted, the recording occasionally works fine when the machine is not attended